# MongoDB - Group: conseguir el resto de campos del valor más bajo

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Buenos días a todos. Tengo una duda sobre si es posible cierta funcionalidad con el $group de mongodb. Digamos que tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
mongoose.model('opiniones').aggregate([
    { $match: { item: item._id } },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$tienda",
            oldest_op: { $min: "$date" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            tienda: "$_id",
            oldest_op: "$oldest_op_date",
        }
    }
])
```

Con ella agrupo los items según la tienda, y recojo la fecha del item más antiguo. La consulta devuelve un array con solo la id de la tienda, y la fecha de la opinión más antigua. ¿Habría alguna posibilidad mediante $group, de poder **devolver también el resto de campos del item que ha encontrado con la opinión más antigua**? tales como el titulo, marca, etc de dicho item.

Muchisimas gracias por vuestro tiempo, un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar `$sort` y `$first` para hacerlo, prueba algo así:

```
mongoose.model('opiniones').aggregate([
    { $match: { item: item._id } },
    { $sort: {date: 1}},
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$tienda",
            oldest_op: { $min: "$date" }
            "titulo":{$first:"$titulo"}
            "marca":{$first:"$marca"}
        }
    }
])
```

1. Filtras con el $match
2. Ordenas por el campo date de forma que queden
   ordenados de menor a mayor
3. Agrupas por el campo date y coges los
   datos del primer documento de cada agrupación (están ordenados por
   el paso anterior)

Para obtener también la más antigua de cada grupo:

```
mongoose.model('opiniones').aggregate([
        { $match: { item: item._id } },
        { $sort: {date: 1}},
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$tienda",
                oldest_op: { $min: "$date" }
                newest_op: { $max: "$date" }
                "titulo_mas_antiguo":{$first:"$titulo"}
                "marca_mas_antiguo":{$first:"$marca"}
                "titulo_mas_reciente":{$last:"$titulo"}
                "marca_mas_reciente":{$last:"$marca"}
            }
        }
    ])
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu tiempo y ayuda, creo que me servirá. Con este método tendré que hacer otro aggregate para buscar la más nueva también, pero como es algo que solo se pasará sobre la base de datos un par de veces, no habrá problema.

Comment: Revisa la edición

Comment: No se de cuantas formas agradecertelo. Ya lo he testeado y me ha ido fenomenal. ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Marca la respuesta como correcta para que si alguien busca una solución parecida sepa que funciona